# How to open a directory in PHPStorm or IntelliJ (or any JetBrains IDE) from the command line?

Tags: command-line, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is there a way to open up a directory in PHPStorm or an equivalent Jetbrains IDE from the command line? For example, in Textmate, I would just do:

```
mate .
```

to open the working directory.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Use `Tools -> Create command line launcher` and then you can execute `pstorm .`

Comment: Couldn't find that command on the Tools menu on PHPStorm 9.0.2 / Windows. I used Help > Find action and found it but it's grayed out.

Comment: I found it difficult to find this information on the JetBrains website. Thanks.

Comment: This option is grayed out for me too. Does anyone havea solution?

Comment: @svendjokumsen Maybe run phpStorm as root? Actually I run it as normal user and then it asks me for a password, but that might depend on the system.

Comment: Same here, this option is grayed. Running phpStorm as admin didn't helpd.

Comment: `pstorm .` just open PHPStorm. If you want to open the current directory in PHPStorm you have to use `pstorm ./`

Comment: Seems this no longer exists in PhpStorm 2019

Answer (score 57):

*Here's how I got IntelliJ Command-line launcher to work with MAC Sierra 
(v 10.12.2).*

**This works with IntelliJ IDEA:**

1. **Tools** -> Create Command-line Launcher..
   [image]
2. **Replace 'idea'** in the string '/usr/local/bin/idea' with whatever you wish. 
   [image]
   *(I use 'ij'), so for me its '/usr/local/bin/ij'.*
3. Open your **terminal**
4. **Navigate** to the project/folder you want to open.
5. Write **the chars you wrote after 'bin/'** and then '.'
   [image]

   For me its `ij .`

Comment: good old `ij .`

Answer (score 11):

On OS X: `open -a 'phpstorm.app' file-or-folder`

Comment: Excellent solution! Remember "." is the symbol for current directory.

Comment: open -a 'IntelliJ IDEA.app' .

Answer (score 6):

For PhpStorm on Windows:

1. Add the PHPStorm's installation path to the Environment Variables "PATH" variable,
2. Scroll to the project folder in the command line
3. Issue the command `phpstorm64.exe .` if it is 64 bit machine or `phpstorm.exe .` for 32 bit machine.

I presume the same strategy will work for IntelliJ as well.

Comment: This is the far most easiest solution I found :D

Comment: Good!This is the far most easiest solution I found

Answer (score 6):

On MacOs
edit ~./bash_profile
add this line

```
alias pst="open -a 'phpstorm.app'"
```

Source it

```
source ~./bash_profile
```

Now you can open phpstorm in a directory with

```
pst .
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the menu entry for `v2016.2`:

[image: menu-entry]

After that you can open folders with `pstorm {myfolder}`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you see this message 
[image]

for Intellij 2019.+ please check this answer. It uses Jetbrains toolbox.
You just need to set path in `Generate shell scripts` option to `/usr/local/bin/` in Jetbrains toolbox
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050914

and then just run `idea .`
or `pycharm .` , `phpstorm .` etc.

---

Answer (score 1):

So the method `Tools > Create command line launcher...` no longer exists in OSX Intellij 2019.1

You can manually make this change via:

```
vim /usr/local/bin/idea
```

Change these lines appropriately from old version to new. should be something like this:

```
RUN_PATH = u'/Users/blahblah/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/191.6183.87/IntelliJ IDEA.app'
CONFIG_PATH = u'/Users/blahblah/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1'
SYSTEM_PATH = u'/Users/blahblah/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.1'
```

If you don't know the new path then run something like:

```
ls /Users/blahblah/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U
```

or manually navigate via finder, then drag/drop the `IntelliJ IDEA.app` icon from finder into your cli to copy across the full path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the JetBrains toolbox, you can configure the shell script for each IDE by going to

1. settings of the IDE in the toolbox (three dots > settings)
2. configuration
3. shell script name

Set it to any text you want

Answer (score 0):

I`m using JetBrains Toolbox to get the latest updates. And the only solution which worked for me (macOS) is:

1. Add the following function into `~/.bash_profile`

```
phpstorm-open-current-path() {
    PHP_STORM_CH=~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PhpStorm/ch-0
    PHP_STORM_LATEST_VERSION=$(ls -rA1 "${PHP_STORM_CH}" | head -1)
    open -a "${PHP_STORM_CH}/${PHP_STORM_LATEST_VERSION}/PhpStorm.app"
}
```

2. Reload the changes by opening a new terminal, or running the following command in the current one:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

3. Use it:

```
cd <PROJECT_DIR>
phpstorm-open-current-path
```

It should be pretty easy to adopt it for any other IDE/OS.

Answer (score 0):

1- add the phpstorm installation path to the path system variable

2- in project folder in address bar type "cmd".

3- in cmd type "phpstorm64 .".

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it did it on macOS:

1. navigate to `/usr/local/bin` directory in your terminal
2. create the file `/usr/local/bin/idea`. in the terminal paste: `sudo vim idea`
3. paste the following into the file (this was pulled from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#standalone):

```
#!/bin/sh

open -na "IntelliJ IDEA.app" --args "$@"
```

4. save file in vim (esc -> shift + : -> wq! -> enter)
5. change the file permissions of newly created file: `sudo chmod 755 idea`
6. in your terminal, navigate to the code directory you would like to open in intelliJ
7. type `idea .` and it should open entire directory in intelliJ

Hope this helps!