# Open another IntelliJ IDEA project from command line

Tags: command-line, intellij-idea

So I am creating a program that can automatically open an IntelliJ IDEA Project (.ipr) from the command line. I have it successfully opening with the following command:

```
Path\To\idea.exe Path\To\ProjectFile\project.ipr
```

However, if a project is already currently open in IntelliJ IDEA, it will not open a new one in a new window. IT is possible to open a new project in a new window by doing File -> Open... But is there a way to do this via a commandprompt argument (maybe some sort of flag or something?)?

Comment: Can't reproduce with IDEA 12.0.4, new project is open in another frame.

Answer (score 20):

You can create command-line launcher in IntelliJ IDEA:
Tools->Create command line Launcher

This answer can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592203/4191683

Comment: Good answer! tl;dr: the feature is already supported by IntelliJ, it's just not enabled by default.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone else runs into this issue. Just recreate the shell command in Tools -> Create command line Launcher. A fresh launcher worked after update.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly add a path of IntelliJ till bin to an environment variable.

C:\Users\XXXXX.XXXXX\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2\bin

then open command line and enter  `idea64 <path_to_folder_where_the_project/code_lies>`

This will open IntelliJ with a given path.

Answer (score 3):

(Re)creating the `idea` shell command from the Tools menu works for IntelliJ 2019.x. Just make sure to open a new terminal session once you (re)create the shell command. Then you can open, one or more, projects from the terminal.

```
idea <my_project>
idea <my_other_project>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you see this message 
[image]

for Intellij 2019.+ please check this answer. It uses Jetbrains toolbox.
You just need to set path in `Generate shell scripts` option to `/usr/local/bin/` in Jetbrains toolbox
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050914

and then just run `idea .`
or `pycharm .` etc.

Comment: oh don't forget to restart toolbox :)

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu Snap

If you are on Ubuntu and/or you installed IntelliJ using Snap, you'll get the following message when you try Tools -> Create Command-line Launcher...

```
You installed the IDE using Snap package manager, so 'idea' command should be already available. If it is not, please make sure '/snap/bin' is included in the $PATH variable.
```

[image]

This is slightly incorrect. Based on [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#standalone), and verifiable by doing `ls /snap/bin`, the executable is either `intellij-idea-community` or `intellij-idea-ultimate`. As mentioned in the dialog, you can (if you haven't already), add `/snap/bin` to your PATH, or you can simply (from the directory you want to open)

`/snap/bin/intellij-idea-community . &`

If you don't want IntelliJ dumping a bunch of junk into Stdout, you can do

`/snap/bin/intellij-idea-community . > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using older Intellij IDEA 2016. What worked for me is to instruct the launcher to use python2 instead of default python which for me is python3.

So changing `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python2` in `/usr/local/bin/idea` worked for me.