# Create Command-line Launcher Intellij not found

Tags: javascript, java, spring, typescript, intellij-idea

I would like to use

```
idea pom.xml
```

from command line to launch a simple Maven project, and so I think I need to configure using "Create Command-line Launcher" the script path, but I cannot find it in Intellij Ultimate, if I search it in File / Settings I can find it, but then if I add a keyboard shortcut it doesn't work.

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: What OS do you use? This option is not available on Windows, otherwise you can find it in the Tools menu.

Comment: I'm in linux and it doesn't exist also. Version community 2019.1 EAP. If I try with find action, it is displayed grayed out.

Comment: Discovered that when using Jetbrains Toolbox, there is an official way to generate the script. Enter in the toolbox->settings (the gear next to the 'Log in' button), there will be a "Generate shell scripts" option and location to set. However, even after setting that, and restarting the toobox, it did not generate the script in that path for me.

Comment: Lol.. dumb me.. just take care not to set there a folder that you can only access with sudo. If you do that, it will fail silently the creation of the script. I have set /usr/local/bin and it failed... sorry

Answer (score 44):

For **Mac OS** with +2019 Intellij:

1. You'll need [JetBrains ToolBox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/)
2. Turn on Generate shell scripts (no longer in tools > create command line launcher)
   [image]
3. Set path to /usr/local/bin/
4. Delete your old executable in /usr/local/bin/
5. Quit and re-launch toolbox

Comment: Mine wasn't creating on `/usr/local/bin`. Figured it was because of permissions and had it create on `/home/lucas/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin` instead. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I had to echo my Path first with echo $PATH then I figured I had to use /Users/lmuzquiz/bin instead

Comment: Also works on linux

Comment: for macOS:  I tried several path , only when I set ```/Users/[WHO ARE YOU]/bin```,  It works.

Comment: It was step 5 that was missing for me :)

Comment: If you are getting the error `/usr/local/bin now writable` or something along this line, then try this command `sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin` . Worked for me.  Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-6792

Comment: @Sulphur This works for me :)

Answer (score 6):

As I said in the comments of the question.

At least when using Idea Community 2019.1 EAP + Jetbrains Toolbox, even in Linux that option is disabled.

You must access the Jetbrains Toolbox->settings (the gear next to the 'Log in' button), there will be a "Generate shell scripts" option and location to set.
Set a location that you can access without sudo, and put that location on your PATH or copy the generated script to a path like /usr/local/bin.

I needed that to be able to use kscript --idea xxxx.kts
(putting this here so that the next person googling that finds the answer :) )

Answer (score 5):

This option is not available on **Windows**, otherwise you can find it in the **Tools** menu.

`Tools` | **Create Command-line Launcher** (available on Mac/Linux).

If IDE installation is managed by the [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/), launcher options will not be available in the IDE and you should use Toolbox settings to create a launcher instead.

- [Shell scripts setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5yzI.png)
- [Per IDE script name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aXjl.png)

Answer (score 3):

When installing the 2019.1 IDE version via toolbox, you need first to remove the previously generated Command-Line Launcher (e.g. via Tools | Create Command-line Launcher)

Then Enable the Generate Shell script option ToolBox and specify the same path that was used before (e.g /use/local/bin/)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, installing `IntelliJ IDEA` as a **snap** package automatically creates the command-line launcher named `intellij-idea-community` or `intellij-idea-ultimate`. The **Tools | Create Command-line** Launcher command is therefore **not** available.

Check [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html?keymap=primary_visual_studio) for more information on enabling it on **Windows,macOS and Linux**.

Answer (score 0):

For Toolbox version: after a long search I ended up writing this snippet and putting it in `~/.profile`

```
alias idea="$(find ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "2*" -not -name "*plugins" -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 1 | rev | cut -d ' ' -f '1' | rev)/bin/idea.sh"
```

Here's a gist with this command https://gist.github.com/tiriana/9a163cd5436158d93c89e0d20b99caa9.js