# Is it possible to open a C# solution in Rider via the command line?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, rider

It's possible with VS code via installing a shell command, as seen in this SO question: [How to open Visual Studio Code from the command line on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx)

Is the same thing possible with Jetbrain's Rider?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to open any file, folder, or solution and project in Rider for editing.
Here is a corresponding [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Opening_Files_from_Command_Line.html).
If you use a standalone Rider, you need to create a shell script. Call the action "Tools | Create Command-Line Launcher...". Then you will be able to call `rider` in a terminal as the shell script is by default created in `/usr/local/bin`.
In the case of using Toolbox installations, all scripts should be generated using Toolbox. Take a look at [Create Command-line Launcher Intellij not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351096/create-command-line-launcher-intellij-not-found) to find out how to set it in Toolbox.
[image: toolbox]

Answer (score 0):

Rider, in my case at least, and I installed it on Linux via snap, comes with a built-in `rider` command. It does open Rider, however, the issue is that the terminal becomes an output for logs from Rider. Additionally, as soon as I close the terminal, Rider gets closed as well. I guess the Rider process becomes a child process of the shell instance that I used to invoke it.