# Can I import settings and open a project on IntelliJ from windows command line?

Tags: batch-file, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ on a desktop computer that resets everyday. So everyday I have to import my settings, restart the launcher and then open my project using the small explorer window.

Is there a way to do all this from command line in batch ? Fortunatly, the path to IntelliJ's executable, for my exported settings and for my project are always the same.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304169/how-to-open-a-directory-in-phpstorm-or-intellij-or-any-jetbrains-ide-from-the/41592203#41592203) but it did not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to import the settings just create a copy of the [current settings directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) and copy it back. Or [relocate](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207240985) the config directory some some location where it will persist.

Opening the project from the command line is also possible, supply the full project directory path to the launcher.

Comment: Starting idea.exe or idea64.exe with my project directory as parameter just open the directory with explorer. `start "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.2\bin\idea64.exe" E:\Programmation\SocialPlatformer`

Comment: Sorry, can't confirm, this command starts IDEA and opens the project for me. You may try with the latest version.

Comment: My bad, I was missing a `""`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program Well thank you very much !